# Git: Change authors through history

Tags: git, version-control, git-filter-branch, git-rewrite-history

I work on a shared lab system with another person on a project. We have both been working on a project so we use the same user on the machine, but we are testing different parts of a code so we each maintain a separate git repository. I made multiple branches, one tag, and have setup a GitHub repository to mirror this repository. After pushing the full repo to GitHub, I realised I hadn't setup the `user.name` and `user.email` for my local version of the repository (globally set by the my colleage to their `user.name` and `user.email`). So, all my commits are attributed to them.

How do I rewrite the history (a lot of commits, so interactive `rebase` is not an option, and already pushed to remote so `filter-branch` is not an option)?
Is there any hope?

Thanks in advance.

P.S.: It's okay if the SHA1 history of the repo changes as long as I get the authors changed across the branches and can safely push it to remote.

I tried `git rebase` with `-r --root` and `--ammend --no-edit` but it didn't edit for all branches and tags, and I tried `git filter-branch` and ended up messing up my local repository (thankfully had the remote untouched so erased the previous one and cloned the repo again).

Comment: “How do I rewrite the history (a lot of commits, so interactive rebase is not an option, and already pushed to remote so filter-branch is not an option)?”—The only question is if you can rewrite the remote repository.

Comment: That linked question asks about the effectively deprecated git-filter-repo(1) but the answer uses git-filter-repo(1) (third-party) which is good.

Comment: Meant to write “effectively deprecated git-filter-branch(1)” :)